# I got admonished (correctly), but the comment was still added

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts, automatic-comments

I should start by saying I got what I wanted, except it would be nice if I could choose "It's OK but I'm lazy and want to add one of the template comments".

For [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/861649) of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12950307/256431) I wanted to mark it as a link-only answer, even though I knew it was presumably otherwise correct.

The system admonished me but still really added the comment. Like I said, what I wanted, but inconsistent nonetheless.

In fact gnat was fixing it, via Review > Edit, while I was being lazy, so I'd delete the comment except that I'm mentioning it here on meta. Gnat has mentioned in the comments that his review edit was rejected too! I see that as a separate bug. He changed it manually afterwards.

Comment: On what ground did you recommend deletion? The answer gives the **code** required by the op and links to the **official** documentation of the method.

Comment: by the way my Review->Edit was rejected with silly message like "this answer is good enough already"; I edited answer from _outside_ of review

Comment: @gnat - You can't improve something even if you see ways to improve it?  Why do we even have people doing manual reviews if the system allegedly knows what's best... Sure, the answer wasn't delete or even downvote worthy, but you made it upvote-worthy.

Comment: @assylias Exactly, I should have got admonished. But as it was the answer didn't expand the link like we've decided you need to do. I wanted the comment to be added, and for a moment I thought I'd helped gnat decide to fix it, until I saw his review was a minute before mine.

Comment: @jmort253 you mean, Big Brother is watching us?

Comment: @gnat That's definitely a bug then too!

Comment: @gnat - Just feels a little too scripted. Why have people indicate what actions should be taken on the post if the system is just going to tell you you're wrong... I can see it tripping people up purposely with close votes... but every answer could use some form of improvement... even good answers... that's a good thing...

Comment: @jmort253 yeah, in this case it was especially embarrassing: edit idea was pretty obvious since OP and answerer discussed missing details in comments :)

Comment: And after all this gnat and I wouldn't have got an extra review count, but I assume WATTO Studios would, for doing nothing :-|

Comment: @jmort253 The system won't *always* tell you what to do.  As a result of a lot of poor reviews a handful of posts that normally wouldn't be added to the queue are stuck in, with a know "correct" decision base on actions that have already taken place.  If the reviewer is inconstant with that action (frequently) it can indicate they are a poor reviewer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a bug in the "recommend delete" case combined with audit tasks.  This will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: For other bugs I normally wait until I can see it fixed before accepting an answer, but in this case I don't want to be seen as a "poor reviewer" by often doing this just to see if I can't anymore.

Comment: Geoff, would this fix also include the "edit sub-case" described in [question comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152273/i-got-admonished-correctly-but-the-comment-was-still-added#comment437430_152273 "wow script is smarter in editing than the guy with three Copy Editor badges")? _Review->Edit was rejected with silly message like "this answer is good enough already"_